# trying to read a text file data into an array to be manipulated then spit back out

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My aim is to take the data from the file, split it up and place them into an array for future modification.

The is what the data looks like:

```
course1-Maths|course1-3215|number-3|professor-Mark

sam|scott|12|H|3.4|1/11/1991|3/15/2012

john|rummer|12|A|3|1/11/1982|7/15/2004

sammy|brown|12|C|2.4|1/11/1991|4/12/2006

end_Roster1|
```

I want to take maths, 3215, 3 and Mark and put into an array,
then sam scott 12 H 3.4 1/11/1991 3/15/2012.

This is what I have so far:

```
infile.open("file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
while(!infile.eof())
{
    while ( getline(infile, line, '-') )
    {
        if ( getline(infile, line, '|') )
        {
            r = new data;
            r->setRcourse_name(line);
            r->setRcourse_code(3);//error not a string
            r->setRcredit(3);//error not a string pre filled
            r->setRinstructor(line);

            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to view it nothing is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly line 1 is very different to the remaining lines so you need a different parsing algorithm for them. Something like:

```
bool first = true;
while(!infile.eof()) 
    {
        if (first) 
            {
            // read header line
            first = false;
            }
        else 
            {
            // read lines 2..n
            }   
    }
```

Reading lines 2..n can be handled by making a stringstream for each line, then passing that in to another getline using '|' as a delimeter, to get each token (sam, scott, 12, H, 3.4, 1/11/1991, 3/15/2012)

```
if (getline(infile, line, '\n')) 
    {
    stringstream ssline(line);
    string token;
    while (getline(ssline, token, '|'))
        vector.push_back(token);
    }
```

Reading the header line takes the exact same concept one step further where each token is then further parsed with another getline with '-' as a delimiter. You'll ignore each time the first tokens (course1, course1, number, professor) and use the second tokens (Maths, 3215, 3, Mark).

Answer (score 1):

You are completely ignoring the line that you get inside the condition of the nested while loop. You should call getline from a single spot in your while loop, and then examine its content using a sequence of if-then-else conditions.